# K5 Graph Avoidance Coloring Game

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory

**Graph Avoidance Game**

Two players take turns coloring the edges of the complete graph, $K_5$. The first player colors edges blue and the second player colors edges red.  To win, the player must force their opponent to create a triangle with their colors.

I want to prove that the second player can always win.

Also, is it possible that some player can always force a red and blue C5?

Comment: There aren't that many possible configurations.  It should be pretty straightforward to construct the complete game tree on a computer and find the winner.

Comment: There is a useful heuristic: if some player colors some $V$, he/she cannot play on the third side: let us call this an obstruction. The second player cannot lose by xavier's observation, and since the first player gets the first obstruction, the first player always loses if the second player goes with the *parallel* approach.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  Could you please expound?  I am not familiar with xavier's observation.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not an answer, but I need to post a graph.)

The question poser is not correct "that a draw isn't possible under $K_5$" as the following example illustrates:

[image]