# Counting permissible sequences in a graph coloring game

Tags: graph-theory

This question is a direct descendent of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210366/k5-graph-avoidance-coloring-game), and is related to a number of other graph-coloring problems, but differs from them in a key provision.

Consider the complete undirected graph $K_5$ and the following two-player game.  Player 1 chooses an edge and colors it blue; then player 2 chooses an uncolored edge and colors it red.  The players continue alternating in this way until one player is forced to complete a triangle whose three edges are the same color.  (Assume no player completes such a triangle unless forced to do so.)

**Question**

How many graph-theoretic distinguishable games are there?

Two games are distinguishable if there does not exist a permutation of the vertex labels that lead to the same sequence of edge colorings.